# Git aways do a weird merge

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out a weird  thing. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but here it goes:

I have two branches: "Web" and "ios-web-dev".

My `git status`:

```
# On branch ios-web-dev
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I used the following commands:

```
git add -A .
git commit -m "[SIMULATOR] brightness control // get results // local storage"
git pull
git push origin ios-web-dev
```

Here is my `git log`:

```
commit e38c75f73c2d3b1ee40d41f87f1a09c0a51b3161
Merge: 0bc2991 f617068
Author: Mauricio Giordano <mauricio.c.giordano@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 14 01:16:51 2014 -0200

    Merge branch 'ios-web-dev' of github.com:estudiotrilha/InEvent into ios-web-

commit 0bc29916e10861c40aafc208a86e7a4db9fafc4b
Author: Mauricio Giordano <mauricio.c.giordano@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 14 01:16:28 2014 -0200

    [SIMULATOR] brightness control // get results // local storage
```

Why that merge exists and what it means?

Thanks!

Comment: That's why it's useful to start using git with `git fetch` not `git pull`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git always has to work on history.  So if you make a commit and then *pull* commit(s) from a remote repo, it will have to merge that commit on top of your local repo's history.  If you don't have any new commits locally, your local repo will just `fast-forward` and add the remote's commits on top.  However, since you made the one(+) commits, git will automatically merge your changes on top of your history.  You could technically *stash* your changes, pull from a remote, and then apply your changes on top.  I wouldn't necessarily recommend that though.

Pretend you made an initial commit (`1`) and pushed it to a remote repo.  If a co-worker took that commit and added a commit (`2`) before pushing it back up, now the remote would be at `2` (with a history of `2-1`).  Now you add on another commit (`3`) and try to pull from the remote.  Git will realize that your local history goes `3-1`, while the remote history goes `2-1`.  *Where is your `2` commit?*  Git has to get that into your history, somehow..so it merges.  You didn't ask git to rewrite history though (`3-2-1`), so it tries to merge it on top (`2-3-1`).  Now it just applied `2`'s changes on top of `3`, so it must make a commit hence the `Merge branch 'ios-web-dev' of github.com:estudiotrilha/InEvent into ios-web-`.

Now if you tried to push to remote (with history `2-1`), you would get an error since your local repo (with history `3-1`) is missing some history.  You can (**but shouldn't**) do a `git push <branch> -f` which will force a push (and overwrite your local with the remote, effectively deleting  commit `2`).  If you never had made a commit `3` after pushing to the remote, git would have no problem pulling `2` since it can just append (fast-foward) `2` on top of your local `1` (`2-1`).

Sometimes I will do a `git-stash` before pulling to save this commit, but usually if I know someone has made a change that I need and I haven't done much work on the local repo (nothing that needs committed).  An example workflow of that could be:

```
git status # a few working changes
git stash # save your working changes to a temporary commit
git pull origin <branch> # merge in the remote, fast-forwarding your repo
git stash apply # apply your working changes from before
```

If you have multiple commits on your local repo, you can technically use `git-rebase` to get the history "beneath" your commits to avoid this extra commit message.  So if you locally had `3-1` and the remote was at `2-1`, you could rebase your local branch to shove `2` in before your `3` and have `3-2-1`.  However, this is not worth the hassle (in my opinion) and beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Why would a rebase be a hassle? It has two clear advantages; it gives a cleaner history that's more friendly to bisecting and it keeps conflict resolution in the commit itself.

Comment: You should always rebase, it should be your default work-flow. Two things for you to consider if you think rebasing a hassle: `git pull --rebase` and [git-smart](https://github.com/geelen/git-smart).

Comment: It's not necessarily the hassle, but as far as the scope of the question.  Don't think it needs an explanation to answer OP.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody else had already pushed a change to the branch you're on. When you did `git pull`, git fetched the changes already on origin, and merged them into your local copy. The is *why* you're running `git pull`, that's explicitly what it's for.

Git will clearly explain what it's doing, if you look at its output between your commands.

Comment: So if I did `git pull` without making any changes in local and THEN make some changes, it wouldn't merge?

Comment: Unless somebody had made changes in that window, but really all you need to do is *try* pushing. Git will warn you if there are changes you need to pull first.